# While and Do-While Loops

Tags: loops, while-loop, do-while, pseudocode

Would this be the correct way to use a WHILE and DO…WHILE loop?

These two examples of a loop were suggested to me by another user so, I thought I would pop them into my pseudocode to see how they looked.

The pseudocode written is for a program that calculates the area of a room in order to purchase cans of paint.

```c
Start
    Display "Enter room length"
    Input roomLength
    Display "Enter room width"
    Input roomWidth
    Display "Enter room height"
    Input roomHeight
    Display "Enter number of doors"
    // Use a WHILE loop to validate input for doors
    While doors < 0 Display "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number of doors:" 
        Input doors 
    End While
    Display "Enter number of windows"
    Do If windows < 0 Then
        Display "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number of windows:" 
        Input windows 
    End If Loop While windows < 0
    Set paintCans = (L x W x H) - (20 sq. ft. per door & 15 sq. ft. per window) / (400 sq. ft. per gallon)
    Display "Total cans of paint is", + paintCans
End
```

Comment: A While loop is executed 0 to N times.  A Do-while loop is executed 1 to N times.  The choice is if you want to execute the code zero or one time.

Comment: You have tried to use two different loop styles for two cases where the input-validation is *exactly* the same. So there should be no reason to use two different loop constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Go through that code yourself:

Upon the first evaluation of `doors < 0`: What *is* the value of doors? The snippet we see here does not give us any clue, so it'll depend on the actual language (here your tag states that it's pseudo-code).

*If* it defaults to `0`, you'll *never* get a chance to input the number of doors, because the condition `doors < 0` will never be *true*.

Otherwise, *if* it defaults to *-1*, you display the error message *before* the user has entered any number. Not quite user friendly.

If an uninitialized value defaults to something else, and/or can't be evaluated, you might run into an error condition when the first `while` condition is evaluated.

Similar steps for the second loop: Outcome will depend on the default, and you're displaying an error message before any value has been entered.

I guess that this means, it's *not* the correct way to use such a loop. Though in general, you can make both ways work.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on the usage of While loops for the input of doors and windows in my pseudocode and added an If-then-else statement for the area. Hopefully, I wrote the code correctly.

```
Start
DECLARE REAL roomLength, roomWidth, roomHeight, area
DECLARE INTEGER doors, windows // Integer variables will be whole numbers
DISPLAY "Enter room length"
INPUT roomLength
DISPLAY "Enter room width"
INPUT roomWidth
DISPLAY "Enter room height"
INPUT roomHeight

DISPLAY "Enter number of doors"
// Use a WHILE loop to validate input for doors
WHILE doors < 1
DISPLAY "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number of doors:"
INPUT doors
END WHILE

DISPLAY "Enter number of windows"
// Use WHILE loop to validate input for windows
While windows < 1
DISPLAY "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number of windows:"
INPUT windows
END WHILE

Set area = (L x W x H) - (20 sq. ft. per door & 15 sq. ft. per window)
// USE IF-THEN-ELSE statement for square footage
IF area is <= 400 square feet Then
DISPLAY “One can of paint is needed”
Else
DISPLAY “Two cans of paint are needed”
END IF
END
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, rather a refinement/edit of the question. And it suffers from the same problems that I mention in my answer. IMHO this is still not correct usage - or at least not very user friendly to show the error message before they ever get a chance to enter any value

Comment: @OlafKock my professor has required us to validate two types of loops within our pseudocode. If you find the loops I've chosen to be insufficient, which two types of loops would you recommend to make my program more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

This question could be answered in many different ways. We could for instance have a loop over an array that has the 5 different input prompts and for each get the input, and collecting those in a second array.

An inner loop can serve to make sure the input value is not negative.

An outer loop can serve to repeat the program as long as the user wants.

Note that your formula for the number of paint cans is not correct. L x W x H is a **volume**, not a surface. Yet I think you want to paint the walls instead of filling the whole room with paint. There are two (opposing) walls with a surface of L x H and two (opposing) walls with surface W x H, so the formula should start with 2 x (L + W) x H.

The below program may be overkill, but at least it shows some options of where you could use loops, and different kinds of them:

```pascal
PROGRAM
    SET sq_ft_per_door := 20
    SET sq_ft_per_window := 15
    SET sq_ft_per_gallon := 400
    
    SET metrics := ['room length', 'room width', 'room height', 
                    'number of doors', 'number of windows']
    
    DO // Each iteration is a new input/output session
        SET values := [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        FOR i := 1 TO 5 // To input 5 values
            DISPLAY 'Enter ', metrics[i]
            INPUT value[i]
            WHILE value[i] < 0  // Not OK
                DISPLAY 'Invalid input. Please enter a positive ', metrics[i]
                INPUT value[i]
            END WHILE
        END FOR
        SET sq_ft_to_paint := 2 * (values[1] + values[2]) * value[3]
                              - sq_ft_per_door * values[4] 
                              - sq_ft_per_window * values[5]
        SET num_gallons := sq_ft_to_paint / sq_ft_per_gallon
        DISPLAY 'Total cans of paint is', paintCans
        DISPLAY 'Do you want to repeat the calculation with new values? (Y/N)'
        INPUT answer
    REPEAT WHILE answer = 'Y'
END
```